# Menu on Button Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, menu

I am trying to make a menu for a WordPress theme but I'm having some trouble.

I would like the menu to be hidden and show only when we hover the button. The menu is a child of a sibling div, something like this:

```
<div id="menuicon>MENU ICON HERE</div>

<nav id="site-navigation">
    <div class="menu">
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I use CSS to make it so that when I hover the #menuicon the `.menu` would show up. And again disappear when we are not anymore over the `.menu` nor the `#menuicon`?

I have tried several things, but I don't seem to get there. Now I have it like this:

```
.menu{
    visibility: hidden;
}
#menuicon:hover .menu{
visibility: visible;
}
```

I think I would need to be able to select the child `.menu` of sibling `#site-navigation` from our hover on `#menuicon`. Is this correct thinking?
Is this something I can do with CSS or do I need to use jQuery?

Comment: Maybe you mean visibility: hidden;

Comment: oh, yes, of course...  it was just a mistake while writting it here. sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The HTML is invalid
2. There's not such thing as `invisible`, it's `hidden`.
3. You can either change the markup or use the adjacent sibling selector (+) or the general sibling selector (~) if CSS3 is OK

-

```
.menu {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#menuicon:hover ~ #site-navigation .menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bYVnd/)

or change the markup to

```
<div id="menuicon">MENU ICON HERE
    <nav id="site-navigation">
        <div class="menu">dsadsds
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bYVnd/2/)

Comment: 1.Yes, that was a typo writting it here, in my code i have "hidden".
3. the problem with this solution is that we can't navigate the menu. as soon as we leave the #menuicon the .menu desappears

Comment: @BoguzDidgeridoo - To make the hover apply to the shown elements, you'll have to nest them like in the second example or use javascript with a timeout and some tricks etc.

Comment: Thanks. i think i will nest them. The problem was that i had a little gap between the button and the .menu (relativ positioned). Maybe i just have to move it closer...